# Dynamically changing CollectionView Cell Size Based on Downloaded Images Using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to build a collection view layout like Pinterest uses.  Most of what is out there is in Objective C, so I've used this RW tutorial:  http://www.raywenderlich.com/107439/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest

The problem is that the app in the RW tutorial uses local images, whereas I'm trying to base the cell size on images that are downloaded via PinRemoteImage but I cannot get the collectionView to properly lay itself out again once the images are downloaded.

Below is my attempt to modify the extension:

```
extension PinCollectionViewController : PinterestLayoutDelegate {
    // 1
    func collectionView(collectionView:UICollectionView, heightForPhotoAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath,
        withWidth width: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {


            var pinterestLargestImage = UIImage()

            if imageDownloads == 0 {
                pinterestLargestImage = imageArray[indexPath.row]

            } else {
                pinterestLargestImage = UIImage(named: "testPic")!

            }


            let boundingRect =  CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT))

            let rect  = AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect(pinterestLargestImage.size, boundingRect)

            return rect.size.height
    }

    // 2
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
        heightForAnnotationAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, withWidth width: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
            var pinterestLargestImage = UIImage()
            if pins.count == imageArray.count {
                pinterestLargestImage = imageArray[indexPath.row]
            } else { pinterestLargestImage = UIImage(named: "testPic")!}

            let annotationPadding = CGFloat(4)
            let annotationHeaderHeight = CGFloat(17)
            let font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Regular", size: 10)!
            let commentHeight = CGFloat(10.0)
            let height = annotationPadding + annotationHeaderHeight + commentHeight + annotationPadding
            return height
    }
}
```

Then I've tried to call `self.collectionView(self.collectionView!, layout: (self.collectionView?.collectionViewLayout)!, sizeForItemAtIndexPath: indexPath)` and `self.collectionView!.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths([indexPath])` inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` once the cell's image is downloaded, but neither properly call these methods to adjust the layout. Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Comment: Have you tried "collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()" ?

Comment: I did try to invalidate the layout, but i get this error:  "ssertion failure in -[UICollectionViewData layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3512.30.14/UICollectionViewData.m:666
2016-02-29 22:01:28.432 PinCheck[1459:61184] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'no UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes instance for -layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath: <NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000000016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}'"

Comment: @almas I cured that error but through testing with breakpoints, I still cannot get `heightForPhotoAtIndexPath` to fire again using `.invalidateLayout`

Comment: did you ever solve it?